# Creating Pie/Bar Graphics using Class Library

Tags: c#, graphics

I want to create a class library which is able to draw pie or bar chart.
i'm using following codes...

```
Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
```

when i used that code visual studio told me you cant use with dll files(Class Library).

i've still problem how can i fix that... o_O

asking more information:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;


namespace KouChart
{
    public class Pasta
    {
        public void PastaCiz(int a, int b, int c)
        {
            float toplam = a + b + c;
            float deg1 = (a / toplam) * 360;
            float deg2 = (b / toplam) * 360;
            float deg3 = (c / toplam) * 360;
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(50, 12, 150, 150);
            Brush b1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            Brush b2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            Brush b3 = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
            Brush b4 = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);

            g.DrawPie(p, rec, 0, deg1);
            g.FillPie(b1, rec, 0, deg1);
            g.DrawPie(p, rec, deg1, deg2);
            g.FillPie(b2, rec, deg1, deg2);
            g.DrawPie(p, rec, deg2 + deg1, deg3);
            g.FillPie(b3, rec, deg2 + deg1, deg3);
        }
    }
}
```

and errors: Error   1   'KouChart.Pasta' does not contain a definition for 'CreateGraphics' and no extension method 'CreateGraphics' accepting a first argument of type 'KouChart.Pasta' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\Muyu\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\KouChart\KouChart\Pasta.cs  20  31  KouChart

Comment: Can you post the actual error message?

Comment: please show us more code and full error details, your current description is a bit too generic ;-)

Comment: sorry i posted more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CreateGraphics()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx) method belongs to the `Control` class. If `Pasta` is supposed to be a control, then you should derive it from `Control`.

i.e.

```
public class Pasta : Control
{
    public void PastaCiz(int a, int b, int c)          
    { ... }
}
```

By the way, if you are writing a control, you would want to draw it in the OnPaint() method, and you don't need to call `CreateGraphics()` because one is already created for you. Here's a very quick example to illustrate, but I'm not a control developer so please don't consider this to be the correct approach.

```
public class Pasta : Control
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    public void PastaCiz(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        float toplam = a + b + c;
        float deg1 = (a / toplam) * 360;
        float deg2 = (b / toplam) * 360;
        float deg3 = (c / toplam) * 360;
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;                           <-- note
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(50, 12, 150, 150);
        Brush b1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        Brush b2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Brush b3 = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        Brush b4 = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
        g.DrawPie(p, rec, 0, deg1);
        g.FillPie(b1, rec, 0, deg1);
        g.DrawPie(p, rec, deg1, deg2);
        g.FillPie(b2, rec, deg1, deg2);
        g.DrawPie(p, rec, deg2 + deg1, deg3);
        g.FillPie(b3, rec, deg2 + deg1, deg3);
    }
}
```

Also note that it would be more efficient to cache those `Pen` and `Brush` instances instead of recreating them every time.

Comment: i'm try to using your codes. but have errors or i missed something.. here is screenshot: http://a1111.hizliresim.com/r/w/t88q.png

Comment: You need to put `using System.Windows.Forms;` at the top of the file.

Comment: lol this is not winforms. this is class library. i dont need using win forms. by the way i resolved the problem thnx to help

Answer (score 1):

this.CreateGraphics(); indicates that a method called CreateGraphics would exist on Pasta.  Where is this method?  It appears that it is missing altogether.  I am guessing you are using code that expected (this) to be a Control or form?  Perhaps pass in a reference to the control and call createGraphics on that?

can you do something like

```
Graphics g = new Control().CreateGraphics();
```

Comment: CreateGraphics belongs to System.Drawing, when i use winforms there is no error. but when i using ClassLibrary this error will appear.

Comment: exactly.  There is no method to call or rather nothing to draw on.  Can you just create a control on the fly?